# input API data into database only get array number not the string

Tags: php, sql, json

I tried to make registration form with province & city (get from API data), i use dropdown with the list of province & city, the problem is the value of dropdown is only province_id instead province, so if i change this code

```
province = '<option value="'+n['province_id']+'">'+n['province']+'</option>';
```

to

```
province = '<option value="'+n['province']+'">'+n['province']+'</option>';
```

it successfull get dropdown province data & input it on database, **but** the new problem show up when i change that code,  city dropdown list not showing up because list city showing up based on province id, im rly stuck here tried to find how can i show city list based on province name no the id

here's my code :

script.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    loadProvinsi('#oriprovince');
    loadProvinsi('#desprovince');
    $('#oriprovince').change(function(){
        $('#oricity').show();
        var idprovince = $('#oriprovince').val();
        loadCity(idprovince,'#oricity')
    });
    $('#desprovince').change(function(){
        $('#descity').show();
        var idprovince = $('#desprovince').val();
        loadCity(idprovince,'#descity')
    });
});

function loadProvinsi(id){
    $('#oricity').hide();
    $('#descity').hide();
    $(id).html('loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php?act=showprovince',
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            $(id).html('');
            province = '';
                $.each(response['rajaongkir']['results'], function(i,n){
                    province = '<option value="'+n['province_id']+'">'+n['province']+'</option>';
                    province = province + '';
                    $(id).append(province);
                });
        },
        error:function(){
            $(id).html('ERROR');
        }
    });
}
function loadCity(idprovince,id){
    $.ajax({
        url:'process.php?act=showcity',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{province:idprovince},
        success:function(response){
            $(id).html('');
            city = '';
                $.each(response['rajaongkir']['results'], function(i,n){
                    city = '<option value="'+n['city_id']+'">'+n['city_name']+'</option>';
                    city = city + '';
                    $(id).append(city);
                });
        },
        error:function(){
            $(id).html('ERROR');
        }
    });
}
```

slice of process.php

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once('idmore.php');
$IdmoreRO = new IdmoreRO();
if(isset($_GET['act'])):
    switch ($_GET['act']) {

        case 'showprovince':
            $province = $IdmoreRO->showProvince();
            echo $province;
        break;
```

and the last it is the view of process.php?act=showprovince

```
"rajaongkir": {
    "query": [ ],
    "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "description": "OK"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "province_id": "14",
            "province": "Kalimantan Tengah"
        },
        {
            "province_id": "15",
            "province": "Kalimantan Timur"
        },
        {
            "province_id": "16",
            "province": "Kalimantan Utara"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your `loadprovince` function to this

```
  function loadProvinsi(id){
    $('#oricity').hide();
    $('#descity').hide();
    $(id).html('loading...');
    $.ajax({
      url:'process.php?act=showprovince',
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(response){
        $(id).html('');
        province = '';
            var result = $.parseJSON(response['rajaongkir']['results']);
            $.each(result, function(i,n){
                province = '<option value="'+n.province+'">'+n.province+'</option>';
                province = province + '';
                $(id).append(province);
            });
    },
    error:function(){
        $(id).html('ERROR');
    }
  });
}
```

you have to change the `province_id` in the value attribute to `province`

that should do the job and be sure that the datatype of the column is not int

Comment: i tried, and result is the list of province in registration form dissapear

Comment: remove the value attribute and try again

Comment: I tried the first solution you gave me and it work but the show new problem, without province_id, list city not showing up

Comment: the list province not show up with your updated data